# Which data structure to store millions of objects?

Tags: optimization, data-structures

There are a million objects that are named and I need a data structure that will allow me to search one by name quickly and insert one quickly. What is the best choice and what is your reasoning?

I was thinking a hashtable or a binary tree but I am not sure.

Comment: You should rephrase your question to be more specific. You should mention at least a language in which to implement the algorithm, possibly a platform and give more details on the structure of the code you tried. If you are talking about plain Computer Sciences algorithms then you should speak in terms of "O" notation algorithms or similar. For example, you say you "thought" in a hashtable or binary tree but you didn't say in which language, which can dramatically change the result.

Comment: Use an in-memory database. Pretty much designed for your use-case here

Answer (score 1):

Binary search trees (BSTs) have worst case complexity of O(Log(n)) for Search(key) as well as Insert() operation. Search(object) is not supported in traditional design (but you can add that functionality).

Since you have mentioned only Binary tree and not BST, the Search(key), Search(object) and Insert(object) will be O(n), O(n) and O(1) respectively.

For Hashmap, the Search(object) is O(n), Contains(key) is O(1) and Insert(key, object) is also O(1), provided there isn't a lot of chaining and hashing function is good.

Have your pick.

Comment: Hashmap has "contains" in O(1). Iterating through the keys to search is O(n)

Comment: @cricket_007: Updated the run-time for every case.

Answer (score -1):

Optimizing for search and for insert fundamentally pulls you in opposite directions. It's important for you to understand well enough your use case to decide which one is more important. Once you know that, you can choose the right structure.

A few options are:

- Vector: constant time insert, linear time search (in worst case)
- tree: log time insert, log time search (in worst case)
- hashmap: constant time for both in many cases, but linear in worst case

Comment: This is a false dilemma because there's a third option: ignore (or at least devalue) space and optimize for both insert and search, by creating a data structure which unions two or more basic structures.

Comment: Sure, you can do this, but as you said, you will need 2 different data structures, highlighting my point.